# posting images to xmpp pubsub nodes

Tags: apache, mongodb, xmpp, publish-subscribe, strophe

I'm reading Jack Moffit's book Professional XMPP Programming and I've got some questions which is the right solution on my current issue.
I'm building primarily an XMPP application where mainly text is published to pubsub nodes, but also images (maybe files and videos later). There are two options which I see to realize the image publishing:

- Users can upload images which will be base64 encoded and stored in pubsub nodes as items (there are some cons to do this: db as a performance bottleneck, but maybe a NoSQL db as an option? Which xmpp server could I use that will work with a NoSQL db like MongoDB) or
- I have to use a webserver to upload the images to, but then

  a. do i need a separate webapplication to attach to as an external       webapplication?    b. xmpp users should only fetch those images which    were published on nodes they are subscribed to    c. I have to keep      track where the image will be stored on the webserver (db table for      that or just the folder/file structure based on the combination of       the pubsub node name & pubsub item id to access an image file on        the  webserver)

Any comments will be appreciated!
Thanks!